# Clear cache from Console app

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there any way to clear my web application cache from console application?
Both of them are one server.
I tried to call reset cache method but reset cache event in console not web app

Comment: Could you detail a bit more what you've tried already, which server you are using, which libraries, etc.? Helping you with that few information will be very difficult.

Comment: it's impossible to clear web browser's cache from console based application

Comment: I have Interval Table and Read from cache in web app

Comment: But Console app insert to interval,after insert i should reset cache in webapp, but How?

Comment: Of course you can `<irony>by rebooting you server</irony>`

Comment: I cant reboot server because of other applications on this server.and i want to reset one of cache

Answer (score 0):

I create a page in webapp that run   HttpRuntime.Close(), in console app call this page,thus Cache reset